# Как в Intellij IDEA настроить vim под dvorak?

Tags: linux, vim, jetbrains

Роюсь уже не первый день в этой теме.

Суть в том, что в продуктах **JetBrain** не могу настроить горячие клавиши, чтобы управление происходило с раскладки **Dvorak**.

Вот официальный плагин [ideaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim).

Использует он `~/.ideavimrc`, но с некоторыми ограничениями. Нужная мне настройка, `langmap` не поддерживается.

```
set langmap='q,\\,w,.e,pr,yt,fy,gu,ci,ro,lp,/[,=],aa,os,ed,uf,ig,dh,hj,tk,nl,s\\;,-',\\;z,qx,jc,kv,xb,bn,mm,w\\,,v.,z/,[-,]=,\"Q,<W,>E,PR,YT,FY,GU,CI,RO,LP,?{,+},AA,OS,ED,UF,IG,DH,HJ,TK,NL,S:,_\",:Z,QX,JC,KV,XB,BN,MM,W<,V>,Z?
```

В **vim** все чудесно работает, но я большую часть времени в IDE провожу.

По всей видимости есть альтернатива, т.к. в плагине явно поддерживается 
`Key mappings`. Прошу помощи в решении данного вопроса.

Comment: не совсем ясно, что именно у вас не работает.

Comment: Конкретно в IDE горячие клавиши от qwerty клавиатуры. На `h` удаление строки на `j` стрелка влево и т.п.

Comment: Сделать через map.<br> По аналогии с ответом тут:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31491711

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал перенастроить:

```
map p v_r
map o v_s
map g v_u
map k v_v
map q v_x
map f v_y
map ~ v_~

map j c
map jj cc
map e v_d
map ee v_D

map L P
map l p

map I <C-End>
map ii <C-Home>
map x <C-Left>
map , <C-Right>
map q <Del>
map h <Down>
map $ <End>
map 0 <Home>
map c <Insert>
map d <Left>
map n <Right>
map g <Undo>
map t <Up>
map u f
map U F

map K V
map k v

imap eu <Esc>
map r o
map R O
```

Comment: И как, попытка удалась?

Comment: Частично... Не все работает

Comment: Вы даёте ответ, опишите, что уже удалось, а что не ешё не работает.